# ErrorDocument and extension less links not working together

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

On my website, I have the following code to omit the extension of php pages

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I also added this code to show custom 404 pages

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Both of these work independently but not when used together. When I visit a dummy link like [www.mydomain.com/pagethatdontexist](http://www.mydomain.com/pagethatdontexist), I want to see my 404 page, instead I see File not found error which is I guess coming from the server, so I'm getting a 404 on 404 apparently.

I've tried moving `ErrorDocument` above and below extension remover code, tried `/404.php` as well. I also tried creating an exception for 404 like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Nothing works.

Edit: When extension code is removed and I visit [www.mydomain.com/pagethatdontexist](http://www.mydomain.com/pagethatdontexist) I see my 404 page. But if I visit [www.mydomain.com/pagethatdontexist.php](http://www.mydomain.com/pagethatdontexist.php) I see bland File not Found error from the server. Maybe it can give a clue as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex doesn't match what you want. With the following i'm able to handle url like :

- /mypage
- /mypage/myid

The regex :

```sh
    RewriteEngine On # Activer le module Rewrite
    RewriteRule ^/(\w+)\/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(\w+)\/(\d+)$ /$1.php?id=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are on a LiteSpeed server, not Apache? This should "work" on Apache, but not LiteSpeed because of the way server variables are *not* updated between internal requests.

However, there is no need (and you should not) omit the file extension on the `ErrorDocument` directive itself. Extensionless URLs are "cosmetic" for users. The ErrorDocument is entirely hidden from users. But, if you omit the file extension on the `ErrorDocument` directive then it would trigger an additional internal rewrite, after the internal subrequest for the error document - which should be avoided.

So, you should include the file extension in the `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: I am using Apache. It should and it does work on xampp but not on my server. Looks like `ErrorDocument` is ignored when extension remover code is present. Aren't these two completely separate directives? What could be interfering here?